# Rails 5: update nested attributes through another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I can not update nested attributes which is related with current model by 3rd model.

Focused model: Profile

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :phone_numbers

  ##Set nested attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone_numbers, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Netsted Attributes: PhoneNumber

```
class PhoneNumber < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

3rd model: User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile
end
```

In database their relation is **profile.user_id = user.id, phone_number.user_id = user.id**

*Question: How can I update Phone numbers when I update profile?*

I tried

```
<%= form_for @profile, url: {action: "update"} do |f| %>
 ...
     <%= f.fields_for :phone_numbers do |ff| %>
       ...
```

and got error message:

> Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'phone_numbers.profile_id' in 'where
>   clause': SELECT `phone_numbers`.* FROM `phone_numbers` WHERE
>   `phone_numbers`.`profile_id` = 1

Comment: I can see, you never accepted the answer to any of your questions. This is one of the site's rules - you select one to notify users that issue is solved. Make sure you acept answer when you have your problem (the initial one, stated in the question) is answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors is super clear and full of call to action:

- add `profile_id` column to `phone_numbers` table to reflect the association between `Profile` and `PhoneNumber` models.

Comment: Now *Profile* and *PhoneNumber* doesn't have direct relation, but they refer **user.id**.
Is there any way to fix the issue by using the shared(user.id) without adding the new column?

Comment: @Alex clarify the question. But there's really nothing impossible in programmin

Answer (score 2):

To add the `profile_id` column to `phone_numbers` table you need a migration.  That is performed using the rails command as follows:

```
rails generate migration AddProfileRefToPhoneNumbers  profile:references
rake db:migrate
```

This will fix your problem with your error.  I can also see down the line you will have an issue with:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile
end
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
```

Your profile belongs_to account, not user.  You want to replace account with user or replace your foreign key with account_id and change the line to:

```
  belongs_to :account, class_name: 'User'
```